# How does ATM determine the card is inserted the right side?

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems

Whenever I happen to try to insert the card into the slot in the ATM wrong side - be it upside down, or backwards - it goes maybe 2cm in, barely past the plastic shield, and is mechanically stopped. The ATM only "swallows" it when inserted the right way in.

This is way before the chip interface enters the slot. Maybe a centimeter of the magnetic strip enters as well - if there even is one. NFC/RFID might work with determining the end of the card, but seems unlikely to help with the side, never mind older cards with no "contactless payments" feature.

HOW does the ATM determine the orientation of the card?

Comment: I've always just assumed it sensed the magnetic strip to open the rest of the slot.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Maybe that's it - I know some cards were released that have no strip - and owners complain about being unable to use them with foreigh ATMs... if that's how it works, I'll be fine with such answer.